Filtering data from other google Spreadsheet sheet based on a combo value from other sheet in the same spreadsheet
I have tried a lot of times to solve an issue. I want to know why my filter doesn't work properly.  The objective is collect/filter a column's values from other sheet ("JARDIM BOTÂNICO") when I change the combo at cell C3.
See a screenshot of my Google spreadsheet.



Use this in place of concatenate:
indirect(C3&"!A3:A")


Thanks it really works this way. Are there some reason for the old snippet "&cell_ref&" does not work?

indirect is a way of telling to look for a cell reference to the concatenated string we are providing since we use concatenate (&) for lot of generic purposes & not for the sole reason to create a range reference or so...
